# Insert a Frame into the component hierachy of another frame

Tags: java, swing, frame

For some reasons (reparent a Xwindow on a Java Application) I need to add a frame into another frame... But it seems it's not possible.
Is there any mean to insert a frame (in fact a heavy weight component) into the component hierarchy of another frame?

Comment: why not use a [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)? I cannot see it being good practice to add a heavyweight component in the hierarchery of another heavyweight component

Comment: Because I have to catch the window XID of my Java component to reparent a Xwindow on it. And it seems that only the heavy weight component have a window XID.